# How to send element id to node js file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I´m trying to send the button id when clicked, to server.js, is for an order processing site

I have tried fetch in my javascript file but I will have to do a lot of them for every products size and price below is my Javascript, Node Js and HTML files.

THIS IS MY HTML CODE:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light bn" id="l1">
    <span class="dif">3/8"</span> Q2.15
</button>            
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light bn">
    <span class="dif">1/2"</span> Q2.90
</button>
```

THIS IS MY JS CODE:

```
 const button = document.getElementById('l1');

 button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 console.log('button was clicked');


fetch('/clicked', {method: 'POST'})
    .then(function(response) {
      if(response.ok) {
        console.log('Click was recorded');
        return;
    }
       throw new Error('Request failed.');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

THIS IS MY NODE JS CODE:

```
app.post('/clicked', (req, res) => {
  const click = 12;
  Product.findOne({id: click}, function(err, foundLList) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(foundLList);
        }
    }
); 
});
```

What I´m trying to achive is to send the button id when clicked to post node js.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch second argument takes more properties. In `body` you can send your data:

```
fetch('/clicked', {
    method: 'POST', 
    body: JSON.stringify({ id: e.currentTarget.id }),
})
```

Comment: Thank you!, I how do I retrieve the data in server file?

Comment: Your request body will have now JSON string, like `{ "id": "1" }`. From there you will need to parse it with back end language of your choice.

Comment: Above you have `app.post('/clicked', (req, res), /* ... */)`. Inside your callback you should be able to do `JSON.parse(req.body)` which should result with JS object. In your example that would be `const click = JSON.parse(req.body).id;`.

Comment: Thank you The Witness, now  with the JSON.parse  I´m getting this error message  Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>).

Comment: Try console.logging `req` and `req.body`.